# in chrome73, the request header unexpectedly bring the cookie to the server when use the fetch without set credentials

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

in chrome73, the request header unexpectedly bring the cookie to the server when use the fetch without set credentials

when i use `chrome 64`, it looks very well, This is my code:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(res => res.json())
```

in chrome73, the request header can not bring the cookie to the server when use the fetch without set credentials

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb58l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for `fetch` has changed between versions.

If you check out [the docs for the `fetch` polyfil](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) it has a section that says:

> The default value for credentials is `"same-origin"`.
>
> The default for credentials wasn't always the same, though. The following versions of browsers implemented an older version of the fetch specification where the default was `"omit"`:
>
> - Firefox 39-60
> - Chrome 42-67
> - Safari 10.1-11.1.2
>
> If you target these browsers, it's advisable to always specify credentials: `'same-origin'` explicitly with all fetch requests instead of relying on the default:
>
> ```
> fetch('/users', {
>   credentials: 'same-origin'
> })
> ```

So the old behaviour you are seeing in Chrome 64 is because it defaults to `"omit"`, but in Chrome 73 it now defaults to `"same-origin"`.

If you want to maintain the behaviour you should explicitly specify `"omit"`, so that it behaves the same no matter what version the browser is.

Comment: YEAH， i find it, 3q